# Flask memory spike when processing big json request

Tags: python, memory, flask

I have a flask app (flask version 1.0.2) that processes xml documents. The documents are POSTed in json format, say like this:

```
import requests
import sys
import json
with open('big.xml', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    xml_string = f.read()
    print(sys.getsizeof(xml_string) // 1024 // 1024)
    # 283
    gid = "FOO"
    json_data = json.dumps({"file_content": xml_string, "self_id": gid})
    print(sys.getsizeof(json_data) // 1024 // 1024)
    # 305
    result_json = requests.post("http://my_server:8080/api", data=json_data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

As you can see, xml files can be quite big, around 300 MB in this example.

My flask app, to simplify, looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from memory_profiler import profile

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
@profile
def api():
    input_data = request.get_json()
    output_data = {"id": "FOO"}
    response = jsonify(output_data)
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

During the request being posted, the memory usage of the flask app spikes to **~2.8 GB**. Memory profiling in the code above is nowhere close to these numbers:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6     27.8 MiB     27.8 MiB   @app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
     7                             @profile
     8                             def api():
     9    617.3 MiB    589.5 MiB       input_data = request.get_json(request.data)
    10    617.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       output_data = {"id": "FOO"}
    11    617.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       response = jsonify(output_data)
    12    617.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       return response
```

What am I missing? What causes this big memory spike and how to deal with it?

Comment: Still tracking down _why_ this is, but put a breakpoint after your `request.get_json` like this: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. Then do this: `import sys; sys.getsizeof(input_data['file_content'])`. You'll see that it's about 1.2GB. Subsequent requests seem to add onto the memory footprint it looks like too, until maybe it's garbage collected.

Comment: @wholevinski I have tried inserting the breakpoint like you suggested, and `sys.getsizeof(input_data['file_content'])` reports the same number as `sys.getsizeof(xml_string)` in the client (~283 MB). And it looks like the spike happens before the breakpoint, with `request.get_json` being the culprit.

Comment: Huh, yeah I see that same behavior as you when switching python3. I just happened to be on a python2 virtualenv to try and get `heapy` working with it. But yes, it looks like `get_json` is the culprit. I imagine it's creating a new string when deserializing which would account for 2X the size.

Comment: Actually, after switching back to python 3, I'm now seeing 2X the original `file_content` size in the memory footprint, not a huge spike. Subsequent requests _do not_ clear that out for me though, so are you sure it's not cumulative? Can you restart your app.py fresh? EDIT: It looks like it'll get cleared out eventually with the GC.

Comment: @wholevinski I'm running this app fresh everytime. I'm fine with the reported ~618 MB memory usage, but not with the ~2.8 GB spike that for some reason is not trackable when profiling.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could safe lots of memory if you don't wrap the xml in a json structure and send extra information using headers for example.

functions like `get_json` and `jsonify` are convenient, but not optimized for low memory usage.. they probably copy the data before processing so it will be in memory multiple times.

i think you are doing something wrong .. the `get_json`function in flask has the following signature: `get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)` you don't need to put your data in it because you are calling the function in the request object. Also you probably don't want to cache the result in memory for multiple calls.

try `request.get_json(cache=False)` and I guess memory usage will go down by a few hundred MB.

additionally I think the json functions are known to use lots of memory: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/11/22/memory-use-and-speed-of-json-parsers/

Comment: Thanks for the tip to remove `requests.data` which truly seems unnecessary here.

Comment: As for the turning off cache - I've tried that before. It reduces the memory a bit, for sure, like from ~600 to ~300 in memory_profiler report, but the huge memory spike is still there (maybe not ~2.8 GB but 2.5 GB now).

Comment: I'm currently looking into other ways of POSTing the request to get around this spike, but I am still curious as of why this spike is happening and not reflected in the profiling.

Comment: I guess the memory is used by internal c functions in python to parse the json string.. creating some buffers large enough to fit everything in... and releasing it already before the next line in the script is executed

Comment: looks like something like: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/11/22/memory-use-and-speed-of-json-parsers/

Comment: Yeah, highly likely this is the reason. You should probably include this in your answer!

Comment: I have added the link to my answer ;)